# Asymptotic distribution of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

Let $\left(\varepsilon_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of idependent random variables with $0$ mean and finite variance, say $\sigma^{2}$, and let $\alpha$ be a real number such that $0 < \left| \alpha \right| < 1$. Now, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, set $$X_{n} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}{ \alpha^{n-j} \varepsilon_{j}}.$$ When the $\varepsilon_{n}$'s are normally distributed, it can be shown that the characteristic function of  $X_{n}$ is 
       $$\varphi_{X_{n}}{\left( t \right) } =  \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sigma^{2} \left(1-\alpha^{2n} \right)  }{1-\alpha^{2} } t^{2} \right)} $$ and, thus, we obtain 
$$ \varphi_{X_{n}} \left(t\right) \to \exp {\left(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sigma^{2}}{1-\alpha^{2}}t^{2} \right)  } \text{ as } n\to+\infty. $$ My question is: Does the limit above still hold if we just merely assume that the $\varepsilon_{n}$'s have $0$ mean and the same variance, say $\sigma^{2}$? So far, I think the answer is negative, but I could not find an example for it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: But if you drop the assumption of normal distribution, then you will get a different characteristic function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for an example, take $\varepsilon_{n}$ having the values $\pm1$ each with probability $\frac12$, so $\sigma^2=1$. Also let $\alpha=\frac12$.

You will find $X_n$ converges in distribution to a continuous uniform random variable on the interval $(-2,2)$, which has a characteristic function of $\dfrac{\sin (2t)}{2t}$

This is not the same as the $\exp {\left(-\frac{2}{3} t^{2} \right)  }$ your expression would give for  $\sigma^2=1$, $\alpha=\frac12$

Comment: I tried with the same $\varepsilon_{n}$'s at first, but it seems a little bit complicated to me when $\alpha \neq 0$. Could you make it clear why we get the result that $X_{n}$ converges in distribution to a continuous uniform random variable on $\left(-2,2 \right)$?

Comment: If for example you take $n=3$, you will find that $X_3$ can take the values   $\pm1 \pm \frac12 \pm \frac14$ i..e.  $\frac74,\frac54,\frac34,\frac14,-\frac14,-\frac34,-\frac54,-\frac74$ with equal probability.  Similarly with other values of $n$ giving values with $2^{n-1}$ as denominator and all the odd numerators.